# python script to iterate through list of data-tables passed from C#

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

Since I'm new to python.. I really don't know what the best way to iterate through a list of datatbles passed from C# to IronPython could be.

I have a class "**MyLogs**" to hold a list of the datatable and then **i pass object of "MyLogs**" class to IronPython engine.

```
// C# Code
public class MyLogs
   {      
     public List<DataTable> dtList = new List<DataTable>();

      public MyLogs()
      {

      }

      public void AddTable(DataTable dt)
      {
         dtList.Add(dt);
      }

   }

  //Structure of DataTable
  S.No  Name     TimeStamp  Result
  1     abc        5667         A
  2     def        6634         B
  3     ghi        7394         C
  4     jkl        8626         D
```

Now I need the python script to iterate through each and every row of the data-tables passed as object from C#.

Answer (score 0):

This question is possibly a duplicate to [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728305/passing-datatable-to-ironpython).

In the accpted answer you can see how to iterate through a DataTable with a foreach like statement. Here is a version that may fit your DataTable

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System import Data
from System.Data import DataTable

for row in MyLogs.dtList.Rows:
    print row["Name"]
    print row["TimeStamp"]
    print row["Result"]
```